# Database structure for variable column names

Tags: mysql

I am writing a script which will counts the number of ticket as per as different conditions and store the count in a summary table. I am unable to understand how to structure my table since there will be more than 1 variables.

[image]

The script will run every week and with each execution a new week will be added. Once the new month starts and scripts execute, a new month will be added and once new year starts a new year will be added. So in a nutshell I have columns which are also variables. Not sure how to handle it.